# iOS UIAutomation from the command line

Tags: iphone, command-line, instruments, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation

I have a problem with understanding of how it works. I want to run my test on the device, so I have the commands

```
instruments -w [...] -t /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Instruments/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.bundle/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate /Users/lazarenok/Default/Shasta/iOS/Shasta/Shasta.xcodeproj -e UIASCRIPT /Users/lazarenok/Desktop/SignInAndOut.js -e UIARESULTSPATH /Users/lazarenok/Desktop/1
```

So, the `[...]` - is the device id, `/Users/lazarenok/Default/Shasta/iOS/Shasta/Shasta.xcodeproj` - application path.

But I guess it should be not like this? How can I find the path for my app like `.app`? Or is my path right? And what should be the UIARESULTSPATH? Where are the results saved?

Answer (score 0):

For the path to the application you used the path to your .xcodeproj file. This shouldn't be the case. Instead you should use the path to your .app file. A .app file is usually created by xcode upon building your application using xcode. To find this go to: `/Users/<username_with_which_you_are_currently_logged_in>/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator`
Then go to the folder corresponding to the version of the simulator you are using and then go to `Applications`. Here you will find some folders with cryptic names. Each of these folders correspond to the applications that you have installed in your simulator. Select the one corresponding to the application you are automating and inside you will find `.app` file.

As for the UIARESULTSPATH, this can be the path to any folder where you want to save the results of your test.

Answer (score 0):

In 2014 with Xcode 6.0.1, you would do something like this for the simulator, naming your simulator after the -w switch:

```
instruments -t '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.xrplugin/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate' \
    -w 'iPhone 5s' \
    '/Users/sohail/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7232A640-A9D2-4626-A2AD-37AFFF706718/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/E71B915E-051D-4BEF-9083-34416D02EC91/RoadRunnerRadar.app' \
    -e UIASCRIPT '/Users/sohail/Developer/clients/acme/roadrunnerradar/ACMERoadRunnerRadarAutomationTests/TestRunner.js' \
    -e UIARESULTSPATH '/Users/sohail/Developer/clients/acme/roadrunnerradar/ACMERoadRunnerRadarAutomationTests/TestResults/'
```

If you want to run this on your device, instead of 'iPhone 5s' like I have in the snippet above for running on the simulator, you'd provide the UDID of your device. You can then omit the long app path I've given above, and just provide the name of the app. Instruments will be able to find it on the device.

Using my example from above, but modified for a hypothetical device, this would look like:

```
instruments -t '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.xrplugin/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate' \
    -w '8532A640-A9C2-4626-A2AD-37AFFF706799' \
    'RoadRunnerRadar' \
    -e UIASCRIPT '/Users/sohail/Developer/clients/acme/roadrunnerradar/ACMERoadRunnerRadarAutomationTests/TestRunner.js' \
    -e UIARESULTSPATH '/Users/sohail/Developer/clients/acme/roadrunnerradar/ACMERoadRunnerRadarAutomationTests/TestResults/'
```

This is not verified with an on device invocation, so please test it. There's a bit of flexibility with parameter ordering.

I do have a verified [UI Automation Runner](http://sohail.io/2014/09/20/xcode-6-and-running-uiautomation-test-from-the-command-line/) script that works really well for Xcode 6.0.1 and the simulator.